# OAuth2 Spring boot Missing required "user name

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth, zooming

I'm trying to use Spring Boot OAuth to make authorize at my app through Zoom (https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/guides/auth/oauth)

I'm trying to open page ( `/zoom` endpoint) my app redirects me to Zoom. Here I'm entering into zoom account and Spring redirects me to the error page:

```
[missing_user_name_attribute] Missing required "user name" attribute name in UserInfoEndpoint for Client Registration: zoom
```

No idea how to deal with it. Here's my code

Config

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/error**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .and().oauth2Login();
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {
        List<ClientRegistration> registrations = new ArrayList<>();
        registrations.add(zoomClientRegistration());
        return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(registrations);
    }

    private ClientRegistration zoomClientRegistration() {
        return ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId("zoom")
                .clientId(/**myClientId**/)
                .clientSecret(/**{myClientSecret}**/)
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .redirectUriTemplate("{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}")
                .authorizationUri("https://zoom.us/oauth/authorize")
                .tokenUri("https://zoom.us/oauth/token")
                .userInfoUri("https://api.zoom.us/v2/user")
                .clientName("Zoom").build();
    }
}
```

At Zoom Application I've configured

Redirect URL for OAuth: `http://{my_host_name}/login/oauth2/code/zoom`

Whitelist Urls: `http://{my_host_name}/zoom`

Also my app has endpoint at `/zoom`

Answer (score 2):

You've to add userNameAttributeName at ClientRegistration and set  to the correct username attribute, it could be "sub" for openId, but also something different as  "email", "id" check the https://api.zoom.us/v2/user response to find which attribute match.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

For me exception occurs when I tried get into authenticated endpoints (in my java app) using *spotify* Oauth2.0 with Spring Boot 2.5.4. I had missing property:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.spotify.userNameAttribute=email
```

which is described in [spring Oauth2 documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.12.RELEASE/reference/html/oauth2.html#oauth2login-boot-property-mappings)

Similar exception occurs for missing property:

`spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.spotify.user-info-uri=https://api.spotify.com/v1/me`
then exception is thrown: `[missing_user_info_uri] Missing required UserInfo Uri in UserInfoEndpoint for Client Registration: spotify`

Comment: Awesome. I was just integrating my app with spotify and this was the issue. Thanks @damian.